# Ajax + jQuery + PHP + SQL Favoriting

Tags: php, sql, ajax, jquery

Hey, I'm new to PHP And Ajax. I'm pretty good with SQL Though. I was wondering how I could an image, and when you click on it, run an ajax request to run a sql query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `favorites` (`uid`, `gid`, `added`) VALUES ($member, $id, '$datetime');");
```

and update the image to a delete from favorites button.

using session for the user id (uid) and gid from index.php?id=13

http://davidknag.com/fav.png

to

http://davidknag.com/unfav.png

when clicking the unfavorite button  delete that entry from sql.

I have never used ajax before and rarely used javascript.

Answer (score 4):

So ajax with jQuery on image class click....

```
window.onload = function(){
   $('.image').click(function(){
    var image_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajaxpage.php",
        data: {
            image_id:image_id
        }
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            $('#'+image_id).remove().appendTo('#removed');
        },
        failure: function(){
            alert('failed');
        }
    });
   });
 }
```

In your php file, you can take the necessary data (the id of the image or whatever) from the $_POST variable and execute your query. Echo some sort of string as a response, and then in the success handler of your ajax call append appropriately. Speak up if you run into difficulty, or have specific questions.

Comment: @orbit so how would this change the image? also, how would i allow only one query to run out of the two? would i use _get?

Comment: You can change the image in the handler on success. Once it is added, the image can be removed from it's container and appended to a different one. In the code above, an example is provided but is probably not exactly what you need.

Comment: Sure thing, this can be a pain in the ass to get working the first time. Let me know what you have implemented, and where things are going wrong. Oh, man. Can you append that to your question, and all further code snippets? :)

Comment: Hey, just take it 1 step at a time... in the php script you call with ajax, just echo 'hello', see if it will come back to the success handler. try to get it to the point where if an image is clicked, it alerts hello. from there, it is smooth sailing. If you are comfortable and have it on the nets, share the url and it may make this process possible.

Comment: Oh, no worries. Add alert('test'); at the beginning of the click handler before the ajax call to test if the click is working.

Comment: nothing.
testserver: http://davidknag.tk/newap/play.php?id=1
edit: apologies, you have to login for the fav button to work. user:orbit pass:david

Comment: apologies, you have to login for the fav button to work. user:orbit pass:david

Comment: ok, you have to nest that javascript  inside a window.onload=function(){ }, adding this to answer

Comment: where? sorry. im very new to js. :/

Comment: no worries, I added it to my answer above. Beware that it will take much effort still before this works for you, and that I may have to sleep at some point.

Comment: document.onload=function(){} where?

Comment: it's added to the answer, just repaste and I'll take another look :)

Comment: your error is in the data piece, syntax error. open your console in dev tools (chrome or firefox) and you will be able to see the errors if you really want that string with the equals sign around it to be your data, put quotes around it.

Comment: hmm, trying to SO through this will just result in frustration for us both. send me an email , brandon@beetree.org, and I can try to help you from there sometime tonight or this weekend... may be useful to start from scratch on a project so you can get a feel for the tech.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with JQuery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

I was just about to type some code, but @Orbit beat me to it... +1 to Orbits answer.